# Sklearn FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. ValueError: kth(=-9) out of bounds (1)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am currently working through a sample tutorial on the california-housing-prices dataste and I am facing this issue when trying to do a grid search for data preparation choices.

Code

```
num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
    ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
])

full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", num_pipeline, num_attribs),
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), cat_attribs)
])

def indices_of_top_k(arr, k):
    return np.sort(np.argpartition(np.array(arr), -k)[-k:])

class TopFeatureSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, feature_importances, k):
        self.ft_imp = feature_importances
        self.k = k
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.feature_indices_ = indices_of_top_k(self.ft_imp, k)
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[:, self.feature_indices_]

prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preparation', full_pipeline),
    ('feature_selection', TopFeatureSelector(feature_importances, k)),
    ('forest_reg', RandomForestRegressor(**grid_search.best_params_))
])

param_grid = {
    'preparation__num__imputer__strategy': ['mean', 'median'],
    'feature_selection__k': list(range(1, len(feature_importances) + 1))
}

grid_search_prep = GridSearchCV(prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline, param_grid, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', verbose=1)

grid_search_prep.fit(housing, housing_labels)
```

Error

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:213: FutureWarning: From version 0.24, get_params will raise an AttributeError if a parameter cannot be retrieved as an instance attribute. Previously it would return None.
  FutureWarning)
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:552: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 531, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 330, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 296, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name])
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 352, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 740, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 693, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "<ipython-input-129-8ca16960996c>", line 11, in fit
    self.feature_indices_ = indices_of_top_k(self.ft_imp, k)
  File "<ipython-input-129-8ca16960996c>", line 4, in indices_of_top_k
    return np.sort(np.argpartition(np.array(arr), -k)[-k:])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in argpartition
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 832, in argpartition
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'argpartition', kth, axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 58, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: kth(=-9) out of bounds (1)

...

  FitFailedWarning)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:213: FutureWarning: From version 0.24, get_params will raise an AttributeError if a parameter cannot be retrieved as an instance attribute. Previously it would return None.
  FutureWarning)
```

Data

Housing is a (16512, 9) dataframe
Housing labels is a (16512,) series

Any idea why this error is happening?

EDIT: feature_importances definition

```
param_grid = [
    {'n_estimators': [3,10,30], 'max_features': [2,4,6,8,10]},
    {'bootstrap':[False], 'n_estimators': [3,10], 'max_features':[2,3,4]},
]

forest_reg = RandomForestRegressor()

grid_search = GridSearchCV(forest_reg, param_grid, cv=5, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', return_train_score=True)

grid_search.fit(housing_prepared, housing_labels)

feature_importances = grid_search.best_estimator_.feature_importances_
```

Comment: Where is `feature_importances` defined?

Comment: Here is the link for the notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/mohamedmoustafa123/chapter-2-hands-on-ml             Ill edit the post to add the feature_importances definition

Comment: Try to reduce this to a minimal example; the sequence of refitting in the notebook makes it hard to debug. The error indicates that `feature_importances` has length just 1, so something has gone awry there. Also, maybe consider the builtin feature selection methods.

Comment: @BenReiniger sorry for that, I have created a much simpler version and removed refitting: https://www.kaggle.com/mohamedmoustafa123/chapter-2-hands-on-ml/edit/run/54815071

Comment: The link doesn't work. Anyway, it looks like the problem is that one of the transformers for targets in your Pipeline needs one-hot encoded labels, but you provide just one column. Though, it's hard to isolate the problem in the current example as was explained before. Especially without data sanle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and what worked for me is to reshape my array that I put as an input (on the argpartition function)
For instance mine had shape (1545,1)
and reshaped it to
A = A.reshape(1545,) //where A is my array